# Freshdesk API CORS issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, freshdesk

I'm trying to access the api of my helpdesk. I want to create a ticket automatically,  like "hit the button" and create a default ticket.

So, I am programming a POST method to my `tickets.json`, but I always get an ERROR:

> SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest para http://XXXX.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json exigia CORS (Compartilhamento de Recursos entre Origens).
>
> SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest para http://XXXX.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json exigia simulação de CORS.

So, as you can see, it's a CORS error

I'm following the authorization requirement by using it in the header of my request

> Authorization: Basic encode64('login':'pw')

But, I still have this issue.

PS: There is a ticket in freshdesk too. https://support.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/112829

Comment: The server must be written to support CORS - it must respond to OPTIONS requests and provide the correct headers, and this is not really related to the Authorization header. The client browser will automatically add Origin to CORS requests. If you are using nginx or apache another approach is to just reverse proxy the backend to a path on your webserver, then the client app does not need to make CORS requests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
I dont know how reverse proxy to my webserver? Do you know any link that helps me?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer, but an alternative approach is to use your webserver as a reverse proxy to the backend. With nginx this can be achieved like this: (this goes in the "server" block)

```
location /api {
  proxy_pass https://api.backend.com/v1;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Here is a link that describes it in some more detail: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html

For apache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: This helps me a lot. But i think, I am not able to acess my webserver. I will see what I can do. THANK YOU :D